# Codeigniter XMLRPC example throwing an error

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml-rpc

I'm attempting to set up an XMLRPC server and client on my server.  So i grabbed the example code in the codeigniter documentation, created the required controllers.  And its not working, so it's stopped me dead in my tracks. The errors I'm getting is inside the Xmlrpc_client controller. See below.

```
Severity: Warning
Message: reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
Filename: libraries/Xmlrpc.php
Line Number: 1889
```

this error gets triggered on this line `if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())`

and here's my code, literally cut and paste from the docs...

Client

```
class Xmlrpc_client extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $server_url = site_url('xmlrpc_server');

            $this->load->library('xmlrpc');

            $this->xmlrpc->server($server_url, 80);
            $this->xmlrpc->method('Greetings');

            $request = array('How is it going?');
            $this->xmlrpc->request($request);

            if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())
            {
                    echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
            }
            else
            {
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($this->xmlrpc->display_response());
                    echo '</pre>';
            }
    }
}
```

and the server...

```
class Xmlrpc_server extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->library('xmlrpc');
            $this->load->library('xmlrpcs');

            $config['functions']['Greetings'] = array('function' => 'Xmlrpc_server.process');

            $this->xmlrpcs->initialize($config);
            $this->xmlrpcs->serve();
    }


    public function process($request)
    {
            $parameters = $request->output_parameters();

            $response = array(
                    array(
                            'you_said'  => $parameters[0],
                            'i_respond' => 'Not bad at all.'
                    ),
                    'struct'
            );

            return $this->xmlrpc->send_response($response);
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code works for me without error. Is XMLRPC a requirement for your server to server communication? I just ask because that library and communication with XML in general is not ideal ... and I'm saying that in the nicest way possible.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the code I was trying to run for XMLRPC from the documentation was obviously for the current version or CI, and I had an older version installed that wasn't compatible.  So i just updgraded CI and it worked perfectly.